# Removing number strings using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to delete all numbers from a string as long as the number ends in " ","grams","g","kg" or "kilograms".

I am using a regular expression but its not removing any numbers. **Whats going wrong?**

For example;  the string `"abc 1231g kjsjk jkdsfkjdkj 11kg"` is should produce `"abc  kjsjk jkdsfkjdkj  "`

Python code:

```
from re import sub
test = "abc 1231g kjsjk jkdsfkjdkj 11kg"
test = sub("[\d]+[\sg|$grams|$kg|$kilograms]$"," ",test)
print test # every number is still there
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is not capturing what you're looking for.  The square brackets `[]` indicate defining a character class, so `[\sg|$...]` isn't what you want.  You should try:

```
test = sub("\d+(\s|g|grams|kg|kilograms)", " ", test)
```

Here, we start with `\d+` for the number, and then use parentheses `()` for grouping and put all the possible suffixes in it, separated by `|`.

To get the output you specified, we need to change a few more things.  The replacement string should be `""` instead of `" "`, and we need to be able to pick up an extra space at the end by appending `\s?` to the regex.

```
test = sub("\d+(\s|g|grams|kg|kilograms)\s?", "", test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets `[...]` and dollar signs `$` do not mean what you think they do. You need:

```
test = sub("\d+\s(g|grams|kg|kilograms)"," ",test)
```

What `[\sg|$grams|$kg|$kilograms]` means is "a whitespace character (`\s`), or any of these characters: `g|$grams|$kg|$kilograms`"; so `[\sg|$grams|$kg|$kilograms]` is equivalent to `[\s$agiklomrs]`, and roughly equivalent to `(\s|\$|a|g|i|k|l|o|m|r|s)`.

What `$` means is "only match if this is the very end of the string".

Answer (score 0):

`\d+\.?\d*` will be needed to account for decimal numbers;
and you will want the order to be `grams|g` for it not to leave you with rams.

```
import re
test = "A test with 1a and 123 and 129kg and 80.5g and 5grams."
test2 = re.sub("\d+\.?\d*(\s|grams|g|kg|kilograms)\s?", "", test)
```

**test2:** `'A test with 1a and and and and .'`

As is the question could mean that you only want to remove the numbers (leaving the suffix),
and in that case you could use a positive lookahead assertion `(?=...)`:

```
test2 = re.sub("\d+\.?\d*(?=\s|grams|g|kg|kilograms)\s?", "", test)
```

**test2**: `'A test with 1a and and kg and g and grams.'`